# Install Ipython for CentOS 6.9

Tags: python, linux, ipython

I have a Linux CentOS 6.9 system that has python 2.6 (pre-install) and a python 3.6 installed. I install Ipython by

```
pip install ipython
```

However, the ipython seems to use python 2.6 instead of the 3.6 I installed. Is there any ways to switch that around?

Here is some extra information:

```
# which ipython
/usr/bin/ipython
# which python
/usr/bin/python
# which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: You need `pip3`, not `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ForceBru pointed out, you need to use `python3` counterpart of `pip`. 
Try with pip3

```
pip3 install ipython
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. after installing ipython by pip3, it works in python 3.6